# how to display servlet by names under /manager/html/list in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have two servlets s1.class, s2.class in com package. deployed them under

```
\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\STEST\WEB-INF\classes\com\classes\s1.class

\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\STEST\WEB-INF\classes\com\classes\s2.class
```

in web.xml did entries as follows :

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.s1</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.s2</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/s1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/s2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

after running tomcat localhost:8080/manager/html/list I could see only STEST folder and after clicking it it says :

```
description The requested resource (/STEST/) is not available.
```

What is wrong I am doing?

Comment: possibly dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068046/how-can-i-list-all-the-files-in-folder-on-tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manager/html/list, just lists the deployed contexts, it doesn't list the servlets.

There is no servlet configured to respond requests to the '/' on STEST context. This is why you are receiving the error.

I am not aware of a default servlet that lists the context mappings but you can add another servlet that lists the available servlets; and map it to '/' to achieve what you need.

Comment: I want to run s1 and s2 separately.. so how should I configure it. (i am new to java ) thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Your s1 and s2 are running already separately. On <host:port>/STEST/s1 and <host:port>/STEST/s2 respectively. 
The manager/html/list, just lists the deployed contexts, it doesn't list the servlets.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run s1 and s2 separately.. so how should I configure it.

Well, if your servlets are in package `com` then you need to place them under 
`\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\STEST\WEB-INF\classes\com\s1.class`. You have an extra `\classes\` in your path. Tomcat cannot find your servlets.