# Java Servlet Login Filter exclusion list not working on entire folder

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, filter

I am working on a web application that uses java and jsp. To deploy it, I am using tomcat 7. I am currently using a `LoginFilter` that will redirect any request to any page (other then the login page itself) to the login page, unless the user has entered their username and password.

The `LoginFilter` looks like this:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    private List<String> urlList;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException { 
        String skip = config.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");
        urlList = Arrays.asList(skip.split(","));
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        String url = request.getServletPath();
        boolean allowed = false;

        boolean staticResources = (url.contains("css") || url.contains("images") || url.contains("js") || url.contains("login") || url.contains("reports");
        if(urlList.contains(url) || staticResources) {
            allowed = true;
        }
        if(!allowed) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if(session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "login.jsp");
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

In my `web.xml` file I have it mapped like this:

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
    >

    <display-name>Test</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Login Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>LoginFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
            <param-value>login.jsp, assets/*, reports/*, reports</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Login Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Now, even if the user is not logged in, I want them to be able to type in: `myurl/reports` and get back the folder of reports (which are just some text files). Currently, if the user does type that in (without proper login credentials), they get this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /myurl/reports/
type  Status report
message  /myurl/reports/
description  The request resource is not available.
```

But if they actually type in the report name (for this example lets call it `report1.txt`) at the URL: `myurl/reports/report1.txt`, then `report1.txt` will be displayed just fine without login credentials.

So what should I be doing so that I can allow an entire folder without login credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Tomcat servlets do not show directory contents. You are getting a 404 not found because Tomcat is looking for the file `index.jsp` which doesnt exist.

Other SO question to look at: [How can I list all the files in folder on tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068046/how-can-i-list-all-the-files-in-folder-on-tomcat)

To enable directory listings you should configure the default servlet to allow for listings with the following `init-param`:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I dont see where you created a servlet in your `web.xml` so ill create a possible configuration here for you:

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
    >

    <display-name>Test</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
          org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Login Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>LoginFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
            <param-value>login.jsp, assets/*, reports/*, reports</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Login Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: For the servlets I'm using the `@WebServlet` annotation within each `*Servlet.java` file, so it maps automatically. That said, would just placing an `<init-param>` tag that is not defined in any servlet work? Or would I have to translate all my current `@WebServlet` annotations manually into the `web.xml` file?

Comment: @Alex Ah okay, looks like you can add an init param using something like `@WebServlet(value="???", initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="listings", value="true") })`. However I have never personally used these annotations so let me know if that works for you. If so Ill be happy to alter my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Alex alternativly it might be worht a try to define a separate servlet for your resources by taking the `web.xml` provided in my post and change the `url-pattern` to read `/reports/*` such that all requests to `/reports` goes through that servlet instead of your default one.

Comment: Thanks! The trick was creating the default servlet and setting the `<url-pattern>` to map to `/reports`. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
final String url = request.getRequestURI();
```

instead of

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
String url = request.getServletPath();
```

Edit: I noticed that your `Arrays.asList(skip.split(","))` will also contain whate spaces:

> 'login.jsp',.. ' reports'

So `urlList.contains(url)` will not work in this case.

it is always a good idea log as much as you can. Log every request. Log parameters an temp variables and the error find you will.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Matter of taste.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I actually don't know how to log a request or use the debugger. I use IntelliJ normally, but since im doing this via command line remotely, I have a script to compile files, move everything, and start tomcat. I don't really have a "run" screen so I can't see logs, System.out.printlns, and I don't know how to debug it.. :| Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: @JarrodRoberson why so aggressive?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I know how to use logging and debugging the IntelliJ and in pretty much any IDE. I didn't phrase my question correctly it seems. I have to use the command line (with no IDE access). When I compile my java code, deploy my files, and restart tomcat, I can't seem to get access to any of the helpful features I normally have.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Wrong link I assume? Unless raw types have something to do with debugging remotely.

Comment: @dit I changed my String to final and made changed it to `getRequestURI()`. I also changed the `HttpServletRequest` to `final`. I'm curious about the white space thing though. Are you saying that even if none of my urls contain white spaces my method will generate them, thus making `contains()` not work?

Answer (score 0):

May be this information will be helpful on redirecting page and allowing some pages depending on self based permission

```
@WebFilter("/secured/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public LoginFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(" loginFilter servlet begin ");
          HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
          HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
          String URI = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI();
          HttpSession session =httpRequest.getSession(false);
          String emailFromWeb = null;
          String loginURL = httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";
          String rootURL = httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/secured/root.jsp";
          String userURL = httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/secured/user.jsp";
          String logoutURL=httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/logout";

          if(session==null){
              System.out.println("false inquery session is null");
              httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginURL);
              return;

          }
          emailFromWeb  = session.getAttribute("email").toString();     



              if  (httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL)){
                  System.out.println("login page inquery");
                  chain.doFilter(request, response);
                  return;
              } 
              if(httpRequest.getRequestURI().matches(".*(css|jpg|png|gif|js)")){
                    System.out.println(" inquery by "+httpRequest.getRequestURI());
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    return;
                }

//            if (httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(rootURL)&&Authentication.isPermitted(emailFromWeb, "RootPage")) {
//                System.out.println("root page inquery");
//                chain.doFilter(request, response);
//                return;
//            } 

//            else if(httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(userURL)&&Authentication.isPermitted(emailFromWeb, "UserPage")){
//                System.out.println("user page inquery");
//                chain.doFilter(request, response);
//                return;
//            }
              else if(httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(logoutURL)){
                  System.out.println("logout inquery");
                  httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginURL);
                  return;
              }
              else {
                  System.out.println("false inquery");
                  httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginURL);
                  return;
              }



    }
```